# Centering 3 different images on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I have 3 images, all images are different widths and in the CSS I'm gonna be controlling the width with a %. Trying to position these images on top of each other + having them centered is proving to be tricky.

Normally to center the images I would just use Transform:translate(-50%, -50%) and set up my width percentage to like 60% and set my left and right 20% all in CSS, but because I'm using a parallax plugin that uses Transform: It cancels out my Transform:translate within the CSS (Chrome inspector shows it with a line through it). I think.

I need a way to center the images, while still let me width % and I can't think of a reliable method.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bcabm0ru/3/

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

li {}

.bubbles-one {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.image-holder {}

.splash {
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -15%;
}

.spotlight {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
}

.man {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section class="falling-person">
  <div class="bubbles-one"><img src="./assets/images/bubble_01edit.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <dov class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="image-holder">
          <ul class="falling-scene">
            <li class="layer" id="bubble_splash-layer"><img src="http://www.sharksharkshark.net/testing/assets/images/bubble_splash.png" alt="" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid splash rellax"></li>
            <li class="layer" id="spotlight-layer"><img src="http://www.sharksharkshark.net/testing/assets/images/spotlight.png" alt="" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid spotlight rellax"></li>
            <li class="layer" id="man-layer"> <img src="http://www.sharksharkshark.net/testing/assets/images/man.png" alt="" class="img-fluid man rellax"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </dov>
  </div>
```

Comment: Use `display: flex` maybe?

Comment: Will give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell me if you don't want the HTML to be different, but I found this way more clean and easier to handle. What do you think? **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcabm0ru/7/)**

HTML

```
<section class="falling-person">

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="layer" id="bubble_splash-layer">
      <img class="splash" src="http://www.sharksharkshark.net/testing/assets/images/bubble_splash.png" alt="splash" />
    </div>

    <div class="layer" id="spotlight-layer">
      <img class="spotlight" src="http://www.sharksharkshark.net/testing/assets/images/spotlight.png" alt="spotlight" />
    </div>

    <div class="layer" id="man-layer">
      <img class="man" src="http://www.sharksharkshark.net/testing/assets/images/man.png" alt="man" />
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

CSS

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.image-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.splash {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -15%;
  z-index: 4;
}

.spotlight {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.man {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm no CSS master and this was what I needed! I believe most of my issues are now solved and everything is back to running smooth! I need to stop over thinking issues... and get better at css ;)

Comment: You're welcome. I recommend watching and following lots of CSS tutorials about positioning. It might not seem like the most exciting part of CSS, but I actually find it to be enjoyable. It is also extremely important. Good luck with the rest!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using bootstrap 4. You should be able to just change your li tags to:

```
<li class="layer d-flex justify-content-center" id="bubble_splash-layer">
  <img src="http://www.sharksharkshark.net/testing/assets/images/bubble_splash.png" alt="" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid splash rellax">
</li>
  <li class="layer d-flex justify-content-center" id="spotlight-layer"><img src="http://www.sharksharkshark.net/testing/assets/images/spotlight.png" alt="" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid spotlight rellax">
</li>
<li class="layer d-flex justify-content-center" id="man-layer"> 
  <img src="http://www.sharksharkshark.net/testing/assets/images/man.png" alt="" class="img-fluid man rellax">
</li>
```

Comment: This does _kinda_ work. The only issue is it's centering the images based on the top left corner of the image and not the very center of the image. That why I would use Transform:translate(-50%, -50%) so it centers based on the middle of the image and not the top left corner.